# Groovy method overloading

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two domain classes on which I want a method in my service to operate. The method of the service will do very similar things to both objects and the property in those objects that it works with is in both objects with the same name. So, instead of making two methods like this:

```
calculateTotalBalancesInd(IndividualRecord indRec) {
     //do something with indRec.accountsList
}
calculateTotalBalancesEnt(EntityRecord entRec) {
     //do something with entRec.accountsList
}
```

is there a neat way (overloading?) to make one method that can operate on either object?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy has duck typing. Simply make your method like this:

```
def calculateTotalBalancesEnt(rec) {
    rec.accountsList
}
```

Duck typing is explained here: http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/08/19/optional-typing-in-groovy/

Another approach, perhaps a bit safer:

create the above method, but make it private and call it from both the public methods you defined. This way the api remains cleaner, statically typed, but the implementation will be groovy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to duck typing per adam0404's answer, you can use switch to incorporate type specific operations. Groovy's `switch` statement supports dispatching on instance type.

```
def calculateTotalBalancesEnt(rec) {
    // common operations on rec.accountsList

    switch (rec) {
        case IndividualRecord:
            // IndividualRecord specific
            break
        case EntityRecord:
            // EntityRecord specific
            break
    }
}
```